# Is there a String.Join()-like method for arrays of any object?

Tags: c#

Is there a method that inserts an object between each object in an array?

For example, given an array of non-zero integers, is there a way to insert `0` in between each element? E.g. change `[1, 2, 3]` to `[1, 0, 2, 0, 3]`?

Specifically, I am looking to do something declarative like `String.Join(0, [1, 2, 3])`, but with arbitrary arrays (not just `char` arrays). A non-declarative way would be something like this:

```
public static IList<T> InterleaveWith<T>( this IList<T> @this, T divider ) {
    IList<T> joined = new List<T>( @this.Count * 2 );
    foreach( T item in @this ) {
        joined.Add( item );
        joined.Add( divider );
    }
    joined.RemoveAt( joined.Count - 1 );

    return joined;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is no built-in method, but you can do it easily with `yield return`:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Join<T>(T separator, IEnumerable<T> items) {
    bool first = true;
    foreach (var item in items) {
        if (!first) {
            yield return separator;
        } else {
            first = false;
        }
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/35djV4)

Comment: +1 for that answer for sure, but can you explain what is advantage of using `yield` here over building full collection at once. I understand that using `yield` we can `break` from `foreach` when one is used. Is that the only advantage?

Comment: @serhiyb An ability to defer building the collection is the main advantage, and it's a pretty big one: in addition to breaking in the middle you can avoid building the collection altogether, saving memory and CPU cycles spent in allocation and garbage collection. In addition, the caller can decide on the type of the collection - a list, an array, a set, and so on. Considering that the overhead is tiny, I think this is a pretty clean approach to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The approach that uses as much built-in functionality as available would be to use `SelectMany`:

```
static IEnumerable<T> Join<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, T separator) =>
    items.SelectMany((item, index) =>
       index == 0 ? new[] { item } : new[] { separator, item });
```

Realistically though, I'd probably go for a custom implementation similar to what @dasblinkenlight wrote up.